# Openlayers add feature in Internet explorer memory issue

Tags: internet-explorer-11, openlayers, openlayers-3

We have a map configuration, where at a certain zoom level we have to plot N number of features, ranging in hundreds to thousands, but on Internt Explorer, if the feature count is more than 2500, than there are memory issues.
So, is it possible to plot the features on the map progressively in a manner, so that memory issues can be resolved?

Comment: Have you considered using clusters?  See: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options that can improve performance and/or memory usage:

Use clustering [Cluster Example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html?q=cluster)

Use an Image Vector Layer [Image Vector Example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-vector-layer.html?q=imagevector)

Use 'postcompose' to draw directly to canvas to avoid the overhead of features

Don't use a spatial index on your vector source (useSpatialIndex=false)

Render features on server using a map server like GeoServer